# How to get Specific Value from Session Array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I have created a session and assigned `User_id` to the Session Variable. When i use `print_r();`  it shows me the the session variable data in an associative array but when i use foreach it gives me many error messages.

Kindly check it and guide me what i am doing wrong here.

```
        print_r($session_dataa= $this->session->all_userdata());

        Session dataArray ( [session_id] => 5943ecd761c336e70240b25d37b054b8 
        [ip_address] => ::1 
        [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) 
        Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
        [last_activity] => 1397982790
        [user_data] => [41] => )
```

I want to grab `[user_data]=> [41]` and store in `student_id` variable. To accomplish this i used foreach loop, but its giving me following error message.

```
$session_data= $this->session->all_userdata();

foreach ($session_data as $data)
{
    $student_id =   $data->user_data;
}

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/students.php

Line Number: 32
```

This is how i am assigning User_id to session data.
**mycontroller.php**

```
                //[[session]]

$data['students_data']= $this->loginmodel->student_profile($currentId);     


$this->load->library('session');
   $this->session->set_userdata($currentId);
```

Comment: You should refer to the `$data` array with key `user_data`, like this `$data['user_data']`. Because `$data` is not an object you can't call it like `$data->user_data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not associating `current_id` with any variable, The Correct way to assign Values to a session variable is given below;

**Controller**

```
$this->load->library('session');

$this->session->set_userdata(array(
                             'currentId' =>$current_id                           
                            ));
```

**View**

```
$student_id                   = $this->session->userdata('currentId');
```

Answer (score 2):

To get your session variable simply do

```
$this->session->userdata('user_data');
```

When you access a session variable using the session class like this it will automatically check to see if its set or not so you won't get any errors.

Comment: do i need to echo this or store this in some variable?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$student_id= $session_data['user_data'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This is what i am getting after using the above mentioned code... `Array 2 Array ( [0] => user_data ) `

Comment: Is the session data an array, or is it encaptulated in a framework's class? Can you print gettype($session_data)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$session_data= $this->session->all_userdata();

$student_id =   $session_data[user_data];
```

OR

```
$session_data= $this->session->all_userdata();

foreach ($session_data as $data)
{
    $student_id =   $data[user_data];
}
```

Comment: Because variable called $data is an array type not object type, you can not use $data->user_data as pointer

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am getting the following error message now `Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'user_data'

Filename: views/students.php`

Comment: I think number called "41" is not a value but is a key value

Try $student_id1 =   $session_data["user_data"]; and $student_id2 =   $session_data["41"];

Comment: In your session variable result like [user_data] => [41] => 

because $data['user_data'] and $data['41'] is empty value